# Using a non swipe able viewpager to manage fragments instead of manually managing them

Tags: java, android, view, android-viewpager, pager

So I recently started using fragments more in Android and I had lots of issues with fragment transactions and back stacks (especially with back navigation) so being the cheap guy that I am I said why not use a non swipeable view pager instead (since a viewpager does all the fragment managment for you).

My fragments are dynamic in terms of their content but the number of fragments themselves are constant.

I have had no issues thus far but I feel that I am abusing the viewpager here. I just wanted to know if using this method is correct or even sustainable?
Will it cause me headaches in the future?

Thanks

I am an Android n00b so please help.

Comment: You can use `viewPager` with `tabHost` widget and it won't create any problem to you.

Comment: @swhaider `I feel that I am abusing the viewpager` --> What makes you think you're abusing the `ViewPager`? IMO, that's a valid use of the `ViewPager`.

Comment: @iruth: I don't see many people using the viewpager in this manner (or maybe I haven't seen enough Android code in my life lol). Seems like most people do the fragment transaction stuff themselves.